# Turn 2D NumPy array into 1D array for plotting a histogram

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a histogram with matplotlib.
I need to convert my one-line 2D Array

```
[[1,2,3,4]] # shape is (1,4)
```

into a 1D Array

```
[1,2,3,4] # shape is (4,)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can directly index the column:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x2 = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
>>> x2.shape
(1, 4)
>>> x1 = x2[0,:]
>>> x1
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x1.shape
(4,)
```

Or you can use [squeeze](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
>>> xs = np.squeeze(x2)
>>> xs
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> xs.shape
(4,)
```

Answer (score 18):

Adding [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) as another alternative for future searchers. From the docs,

> It is equivalent to reshape(-1, order=order).

Since the array is 1xN, all of the following are equivalent:

- `arr1d = np.ravel(arr2d)`
- `arr1d = arr2d.ravel()`
- `arr1d = arr2d.flatten()`
- `arr1d = np.reshape(arr2d, -1)`
- `arr1d = arr2d.reshape(-1)`
- `arr1d = arr2d[0, :]`

Answer (score 2):

[`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) will do the trick.

There's also a more specific function, [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy.ndarray.flatten), that appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: More specifically, `arr.reshape(-1)` converts an array to 1D. But the equivalent `ravel()` is better, as it is meant specifically to indicate a conversion to 1D.

Answer (score 2):

the answer provided by mtrw does the trick for an array that actually only has one line like this one, however if you have a 2d array, with values in two dimension you can convert it as follows

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

From here you can find the shape of the array with `np.shape` and find the product of that with `np.product` this now results in the number of elements. If you now use `np.reshape()` to reshape the array to one length of the total number of element you will have a solution that always works.

```
np.reshape(a, np.product(a.shape))
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy.flat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array([[1,0,0,1],
              [2,0,1,0]])

plt.hist(a.flat, [0,1,2,3])
```

[image: Histogram of Flattened Array]

The `flat` property returns a 1D iterator over your 2D array. This method generalizes to any number of rows (or dimensions). For large arrays it can be much more efficient than making a flattened copy.