# Plot hourly result using Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, machine-learning

I have result of hourly price by using group by:

```
group=df.groupby("hour")["price"].mean()
```

and then I normalize the result by max price by using this code:

```
nor=preprocessing.normalize(group, norm='max')
```

I then plot the result using this code:

```
plt.figure()

plt.plot( nor,
        label='price 1',
        color='red')
plt.xlim(0,24)
plt.ylim([0.0, 1])
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.title('g2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True)

plt.show()
```

but it does not show anything?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear on whether you get errors or just no plot. Are you in a notebook? Did you invoke `%pylab inline`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need convert one-line 2D array to 1D array, but first need reshape by `reshape(1, -1)` because `Series` `group` is converted to a single sample:

```
nor=preprocessing.normalize(group.values.reshape(1,-1), norm='max')[0,:]
```

Another solution with [`numpy.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
nor=np.squeeze(preprocessing.normalize(group.values.reshape(1,-1), norm='max'))
```

Another alternatives are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24867629/2901002).

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':range(24),
                   'price':np.random.random(size=24)})

#print (df)

group=df.groupby("hour")["price"].mean()
nor=preprocessing.normalize(group.values.reshape(1,-1), norm='max')[0,:]
print (nor)
[ 0.55527461  0.28444985  0.43379039  0.86322869  0.00482193  0.12422457
  0.68540035  0.84389197  0.13969269  0.58765517  0.91079122  0.21377175
  0.18937637  0.11074418  0.22449638  1.          0.82941286  0.17569674
  0.83405366  0.28006038  0.44113396  0.96056302  0.83550941  0.34345369]

plt.figure()

plt.plot( nor,
        label='price 1',
        color='red')
plt.xlim(0,24)
plt.ylim([0.0, 1])
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.title('g2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]